# Radio button new line text in virtuemart

Tags: css, radio-button

I am new to coding, I am using the latest version of joomla. I having trouble with the radio buttons in custom field of virtuemart. In firefox the radio buttons look like this:

[image]

but in chrome they looks differently. There is a radio per line then text then radio again.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Also, this works well when the label name is long but not so well when the label name is short.

```css
 .radio, .checkbox {
        padding-left: 18px;
    }
    label {
        color: #333333;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        max-width: 90%;
    }

label, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline;
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: none;
}
layout.css:252
input[type="image"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    border-radius: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: auto;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
layout.css:247
label input, label textarea, label select {
    display: block;
}
layout.css:294
input, textarea {
    -moz-transition: border 0.2s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.2s linear 0s;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
layout.css:231
input, textarea, select, #advanced-search-toggle, input.search-query {
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    padding: 4px;
}
layout.css:220
label, input, button, select, textarea {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="radio" i] {
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="radio" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="radio" i], input[type="checkbox" i] {
    background-color: initial;
    margin: 3px 0.5ex;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    user-select: text;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

I have tried many of the suggestions here, but whenever changes are done, something or another breaks down. Also the incompatibility between Firefox and chrome is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the radio button inside another tag and make it display block, so the item will be stacked.

HTML

```
<div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female</div>
<div><input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other</div>
```

With div you don't need display: block property

Comment: @ace was this helpful?